Is there a word other than "grave" for a burial place?
Is there a term which means specifically "hole in the ground in which one might expect to find a dead body"?  I'm looking for a word parallel to "tomb" or "sarcophagous" or "mausoleum", but which refers to a hole in the ground rather than a building or structure.  "Grave" implies there actually is a body in there, or was at some stage - an "empty grave" is one from which a body has been removed, whereas an "empty sarcophagous" may never have been used - and "grave" can also refer to a structure rather than a hole.
Example sentence - "We do not know if the _____ actually contains human remains."
"Pit" is the best word I have at the moment, but that may be too generic.
EDIT
To address various comments below, the thing I'm trying to describe is (a) definitely a hole in which (b) something may have been buried, and (c) that something is likely to be a human body.  Another example sentence might be:
"There are 29 _____s on the site: 26 are graves, and three may have been part of the foundations of a building".
If there is a technical term (other than "pit") from archaeology for such a hole, it would work.
"Internment" would be good if it can be used to refer to the actual hole, rather than the act of burial, and I'll accept that answer if "internment" can be used in that way.

If the grave is on a cemetery you could use "plot" or "lot".

There's no requirement for a grave to actually contain a body. But the question could be more precise: is it in a cemetery? Is there a hole? or is it just a random piece of earth?

Could you add some further context?  Is this hole suspected of containing human remains but is not a marked grave?  Is it ancient or modern?

An actual hole would typically only exist briefly- the total time elapsed from excavation to internment to back-filling the hole might be a day or two. Maybe "infill" would work in your example sentence.

The word needed seems to be the one rejected.

The word interment carries the sense of burial site as well as the act / ritual of burying. It is in a formal register.
Examples from the internet:

In the course of the works recently carried out at the church a singular interment was discovered on the north side of the building. Six skeletons placed in a circle, the heads innermost and radiating from a centre, were found at about five feet below the present level of the churchyard.                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [Yapton and Ford Local History Group]

It is often used in legal articles:

On Boxing Day 2012 Mrs. Porter-Williams and her son, Richard, visited Mr.
Porter-Williams’ grave and discovered the interment in the adjoining plot.                                [Ecclesiastical Law Association; Dubchurch St Peter; Diocese of Coventry]

Koelig discovered the interment of Mr. Gallaher in his family burial plots.


                                          [Casetext; Roslyn Presbyterian Church v Perlman]
It is not just applied to human burials;

The interment of a ship at Sutton Hoo represents the most impressive medieval grave to be discovered in Europe. Inside the burial mound was the imprint of a decayed ship and a central chamber filled with treasures.                                                                                         [British Museum]


+1 Interment is good, and a perfect fit for archeological sites, but I would use it of formal burials only, something ceremonial, not "informal" situations, such as when a body is buried in a shallow grave in the Pine Barrens by mafiosi. OP's context  seems to be heading in that direction, though it's not clear.

–1 It’s true that interment can refer to the site/structure as well as the act, but the OP wants a word for a possibly-unused-grave.  To my ear, this transferred use of interment implies that the act-of-interment has taken place (i.e. that the grave is used) more strongly than grave itself, not less.  All your cited examples fit this; if you think interment can also be used for never-used graves, could you give some more references to show this?

I was addressing the title question. It is extremely unlikely that there is a specific word for a 'candidate grave', and if this requirement is seen as binding, the question is probably too narrowly scoped. // I trust, PLL, that you DV'd 'excavation' as being far too widely scoped? One might expect to find an underground line in such.

In case you weren't aware, the formatting on my Android mobile appears very skewed. Nice on the desktop but pretty awful on my mobile, it's a 2016 model, much smaller than the more modern ones.

The relevance escapes me, Mari-Lou A.

This is probably the word I'm looking for, if @PLL 's point can be addressed.

I doubt it can; I believe only the title question has a valid answer.

Presumably it isn't just an open hole, but an

excavation
NOUN
a hole or hollow made by excavating

From Collins Dictionary
Although it may share its meaning with pit it is a more respectful term to use, since a pit may be used for a mass grave or casual interment.

We do not know if the excavation actually contains human remains.


Absent other context, "excavation" would not normally be interpreted as meaning a grave. Your example sentence sounds to me like it's talking about a place that archaeologists are examining.

‘Pit’ was the only alternative I could muster, but I’m now wondering, reading your context, whether ‘cavity’ might work?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

What’s wrong with tomb? Merriam-Webster gives as its first definition

1 a : an excavation in which a corpse is buried : GRAVE
.  b : a place of interment

and note that interment means “placing in the terra [earth].”

A tomb may be a structure above the ground - a mausoleum, sarcophagous, etc.  I need a word that unambiguously refers to the burial of a body.
